# SQLite3 Update from other table in Database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have posted the same question in the past, however, I seem to fail on implementing it in my python code.

The objective is to update the table Ships with info already in table Companies. Image for reference. [image: SQLite Tables for reference]

I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3

# connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('PSC.sdb')
# create cursor
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''
    UPDATE ships
    SET "ISM Performance PM" = (SELECT companies."ISM Performance PM"
                                FROM companies
                                WHERE ships."ISM IMO" = companies."ISM IMO")''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When I run it I have no errors but keep having Null values.
Sorry for the repost but really need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample data that you posted I see that the condition:

```
WHERE ships."ISM IMO" = companies."ISM IMO"
```

should succeed and update correctly the table.

But what you can try is trim the values before comparing them:

```
WHERE TRIM(ships."ISM IMO") = TRIM(companies."ISM IMO")
```

or convert them to integers:

```
WHERE (ships."ISM IMO" + 0) = (companies."ISM IMO" + 0)
```

so that any existing blank characters are removed and the numbers can be compared.

Comment: HUUGE noob mistake. Your answer made me go checking what was the Data Type in both Tables. One was Text and the other INTEGER. Couldn't work like that! Thanks for your great help @forpas!